# How can I fix this issue of getting None type

Tags: python, random

```
def generate_h(c):
    if c == 1:
      k = 0.4
      l = 0.6
    elif c == 2:
      k = 0.1
      l = 0.9
    elif c == 0:
      k = 0.7
      l = 0.3
      h_arr = []
      i=1
      while True: 
        x = np.random.random()*2.099 + 0.01
        y = np.random.random()
        if y<=pdf_h(x,k,l):
          h_arr.append(x)
      return h_arr
```

This is my code that generates a value from looking at pdf and using rejection method from given c value.

this is my pdf calculating code:

```
def pdf_h(h, k, l):
if h<=1 and h>=0:
  return k
if 1<h and h<=2:
  return l
else:
  return 0
```

However when I run this line

```
print(generate_h(0))
```

I get None type but I should get a number

Comment: What is `pdf_h(x,k,l)` ?

Comment: Probably start by fixing your indentation

Comment: No indentation is broken, which is why `None` is returned

Comment: Indentation is either very much broken or it's intentional that `None` is returned if `c != 0` and the `while` loop is infinte.

Comment: If `c==0` then there should be an infinite loop. Since you get `None` then something else is happening.  Are you sure that the code you have posted is correct?

Comment: @2brk brother is this the way to talk? I even did not close your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your identation! the while loop should be outside the else ifs.

Answer (score -1):

Your function only has the return statement inside the `if c == 0` block. If the condition `c == 0` is not met, the function does not have anything to return, hence it returns None. This is the default behavior of Python functions when no return statement is executed.

Moreover, in your code, the list `h_arr` gets appended to in an infinite `while` loop. This loop will continue until manually interrupted or until it consumes all available memory. The condition of the while loop is always `True`, and there's no break statement inside the loop. This could potentially cause an issue if not handled correctly.

Depending on your use case, a potential fix could be this:

```
def generate_h(c):
    if c == 1:
        k = 0.4
        l = 0.6
    elif c == 2:
        k = 0.1
        l = 0.9
    elif c == 0:
        k = 0.7
        l = 0.3

    h_arr = []
    i=1
    while True: 
        x = np.random.random()*2.099 + 0.01
        y = np.random.random()
        if y<=pdf_h(x,k,l):
            h_arr.append(x)
            break  # Add a break statement

    return h_arr  # Make sure to return outside of the if-elif-else structure

print(generate_h(0))
```

The return statement is now outside of the `if/elif/else` structure, ensuring that a `[]` is atleast returned no matter what. A break statement is also added to exit the while loop once a value is appended to `h_arr`. This prevents the potential infinite loop.

Comment: Yes my indentation was wrong, thanks for the help, now my code is working.